# Is it a bad practice to use methods like Number() String() in javascript or we shall use other ways as shown below and try to minimize their use?

Tags: javascript, string, type-conversion, numbers

```js
  let num = 231.32;
  console.log( num.toPrecision() );
  console.log( String(num) );
  
  {

  let numStr = "250";
  console.log(Number(numStr)); console.log(Number.parseFloat(numStr));

}
```

Here we can achieve same things that String() and Number() can do by other ways. The above code gives same output. So shall we try to minimize the use case of String() and  Number(). Which one would be nice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is never really a real bad method just depends on the situation you are working on.

`ToPrecision()` will change the original number and round to specific decimal:
Note that `ToPrecision()` could only deal with number and will produce error with deal with string.

> The toPrecision() method returns a string representing the Number object to the specified precision

`Number` v.s `ParseFloat` is almost the same in most of the situation, but `Number` will return `NaN` and parseFloat will return the `number` part when deal with a string that contain some characters and number. (e.g `123ABC`)

Example:

```js
let num = '123ABC'
//return 123
console.log(parseFloat(num))
//return NaN
console.log(Number(num))

let num1='123'
 //Produce error
console.log(num1.toPrecision(2))
```

I think the main difference between `String` and use `" "` is that you can't always and it is very annoying to redeclare the things you want (e.g. redeclare `ABC` to `"ABC"`). (I think your numStr is to show use `" "` change string.

Another built-in function to use is `toString()` to convert to `string`, but `toString` will produce error when you use  want to convert `null` and `undefined`.

Example:

```js
let test = undefined;
//produce 'undefined'
console.log(String(test))
//produce error
console.log(test.toString())
```

I think it is OK to use any of them in the most situation, but you have to notice the small difference. They are not totally same.

Comment: "but you have to notice the small difference" Yaa, I guess I shall focus on that.Thanks